# Image URLs added to ion-list load after height determined

Tags: angular, ionic2, loading

I've had to pick up an issue with limited experience of this technology, and I'm struggling to find a resolution. I believe I now know why the issue is being caused, but I don't know how to go about solving it.

I have a page that makes a request off to a remote server in order to fetch a list, one of the values of which is a link containing an image that needs to be shown. Unfortunately, what happens is that we get these items back, add them all into the list, and then the list works out it's size. Then the images load, and everything overruns.

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="info" #infoList id="infoList">
  <ion-item  *virtualItem="let item">
    <div [innerHTML]="item.innerHTML"></div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Any advice on how I can cause the ion-list to recalculate its height or programmatically do so?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it will work for lists, but you could try the [**`resize`**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#resize) method

Comment: Have you tried using `<ion-img>`? As mentioned [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/#images-within-virtual-scroll)

Comment: @Erevald I don't actually get an image. I get html that displays a clickable image. I don't believe that would work with ion-img. I could try extracting it though.

Answer (score 0):

First load the images and then show them. Meaning that the browser loads the image and one it has done that it builds the view
 This can be done with below js.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    // this is called when image is loaded.
};
imageObj.src = image;
```